# Flag question button remains enabled when you reach the maximum number of moderator flags

Tags: support, flags

I have noticed that when you reach the maximum number of flags for the day, the `Flag Question` button is disabled (as depicted in the next figure).

[image: Disabled Flag Button]

However, if you select the option `It doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate`, the flag button becomes enabled again no matter what option you choose in this second menu (as depicted in blue in the next figure).

[image: Enabled Flag Button]

Then, if you click on the button the "error message" appears stating that you have reached the number of flags for that day.

[image: Error Message]

As I am not aware if this is a feature or a bug, in case of a bug possible solutions to solve this problem are:

1. Either make the `Flag Question` button disabled throughout all the process of post flagging (when the maximum number of moderator flags is reached); or
2. As soon as you choose the option `It doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate`, the orange box appears with the error message. However, if the user chooses the wrong option, this means that it has to go through all the flagging process again; or
3. Simply disable the radio buttons that cannot be selected when the maximum number of flags is reached for that day.

Answer (score 1):

That button isn't disabled because you're out of flags. It's disabled because you haven't entered any valid flag input yet. If you click on the "very low quality" option or click on "other" and enter something, I do believe it re-enables. I can't test this though because I'm not near 0 flags left anywhere.

I think the problem here is that the second dialog actually uses the "vote to close" dialog which is slightly modified for those who don't actually have that privilege (it submits a flag instead of a close vote). Those flags still count as "inform moderator" flags though. Normally, that dialog would display how many close votes you have left for the day, so I guess a good solution would be to show the number of inform moderator flags you have left when you don't have vote-to-close privileges.